# vue.js webpack problem: can't add plugin to vue.config.js with configureWebpack

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli-3

vue.js webpack problem: I can't add a plugin to vue.config.js with configureWebpack

I created a vue.js project with vue cli 3.  I am following the example in:
https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html

My vue.config.js:

```
let webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {

    configureWebpack: {
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                __TEST_MESSAGE__: JSON.stringify('howdy there!')
            })
        ]
    },
};
```

The resolved webpack config looks like:

```
{
    mode: 'production',
    ...
    plugins: [
        /* config.plugin('vue-loader') */
        new VueLoaderPlugin(),

        /* config.plugin('define') */
        new DefinePlugin(
          {
            'process.env': {
              VUE_APP_CLI_UI_URL: '""',
              NODE_ENV: '"production"',
              BASE_URL: '"/"'
            }
          }
        ),
        /* config.plugin('case-sensitive-paths') */
        new CaseSensitivePathsPlugin(),

        ...
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Inserted note for SO: This is messed up!  Should
        // be: 
        // new DefinePlugin({ __TEST_MESSAGE__: '"howdy there!"' })
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        {
          definitions: {
            __TEST_MESSAGE__: '"howdy there!"'
          }
        }
    ],
    ...
}
```

configureWebPack is supposed to merge my plugins with the vue defined plugins.  Why is it stripping the DefinePlugin class out and just including the argument to the constructor in the plugins array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because Vue already includes the `DefinePlugin`, you need to modify it using Webpack's chain API instead of attempting to add a new one.

```js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.plugin('define').tap(args => {
      args[0].__TEST_MESSAGE__ = JSON.stringify('howdy there!')
      return args
    })
  }
}
```

This results in the following config (just an example)...

> ```
> new DefinePlugin(
>   {
>     'process.env': {
>       NODE_ENV: '"development"',
>       BASE_URL: '"/"'
>     },
>     __TEST_MESSAGE__: '"howdy there!"'
>   }
> ),
> ```

See https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#modifying-options-of-a-plugin

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you.

Comment: @jingleheimer you're very welcome. Thank you for asking a good question with lots of detail.

Comment: @phil how can I access __TEST_MESSAGE__ in my component?

Comment: @daniel I believe it should be available as a global variable, just like `process.env`

Comment: @Phil thanks for your answer but I got "TS2304 Cannot find name : __TEST_MESSAGE__" (I'm usign vue&TS if its matter) when I assign as   private items = __TEST_MESSAGE__;

Comment: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/issues/37#issuecomment-135812276